# Simple Client/Server application in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, server, jframe, client

heyho,
I'm new in coding so sorry if this is obvious or whatever.
I tried to code a client/server application. That worked. Then I wanted to build a GUI for the client using JFrame. Well, that doesn't really work. When I run the client nothing happens. But my server tells me that somebody logged in, called "null". But I don't get to enter my nickname cuz I nothing happens, as I said. I
Can you help me?:)
(I started doing the GUI in a different class, so it may be more complicated than needed.)

```
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
    
    public class Client implements Runnable{
    
    
    private Socket client;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private boolean done;
    private ClientGUI cgui;
    
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9969);
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            
            InputHandler inHandler = new InputHandler();
            Thread t = new Thread(inHandler);
            t.start();
            
            HandleClientGUI cgui = new HandleClientGUI();
            Thread tgui = new Thread(cgui);
            tgui.start();
            
            String inMessage;
            while((inMessage = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inMessage + " --> ");
                cgui.getCgui().newMsg(inMessage);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            shutdown();
        }
    }
    
    public void shutdown() {
        
        try {
            done = true;
            in.close();
            out.close();
            if (!client.isClosed()) {
                client.close();             
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    
    
    class InputHandler implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(!done && (!cgui.getOutMessage().equals(""))) {
                    System.out.println(cgui.getOutMessage());
                    String message = cgui.getOutMessage();
                    if(message.equals("/quit")) {
                        out.println(message);
                        shutdown();
                    } else {
                        out.println(message);
                    }
                    cgui.setOutMessage("");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                shutdown();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    public class ClientGUI extends JFrame implements Runnable{
          // Anfang Attribute
          private JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
          private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
          private JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField();
          private JButton b1 = new JButton();
          private String outMsg;
          // Ende Attribute
          
          public ClientGUI() {
              super();
          }
          
          @Override
          public void run() { 
              
            
            // Frame-Initialisierung
         
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            int frameWidth = 1236; 
            int frameHeight = 764;
            setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
            Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
            int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
            setLocation(x, y);
            setTitle("ClientGUI");
            setResizable(false);
            Container cp = getContentPane();
            cp.setLayout(null);
            // Anfang Komponenten
            
            jScrollPane1.setBounds(12, 10, 1196, 532);
            jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            cp.add(jScrollPane1);
            jLabel1.setBounds(12, 6, 1166, 65535);
            jLabel1.setText("<html><body></body></html>");
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jLabel1);
            jTextField1.setBounds(13, 552, 1118, 36);

            cp.add(jTextField1);
            b1.setBounds(1131, 555, 75, 33);
            b1.setText(">");
            b1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
                b1_ActionPerformed(evt);
              }
            });
            cp.add(b1);
            jLabel1.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
            jLabel1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
            // Ende Komponenten
            
            outMsg = "";
            
            setVisible(true);
          } // end of public ClientGUI
          
          // Anfang Methoden
          public void newMsg(String msg) {
            String old = jLabel1.getText();
            String newString = old.substring(0, (old.length()-13));
            newString = newString + "br>" + msg + "</body></html>";
            jLabel1.setText(newString);
            
          }
         
          
          public void b1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            setOutMessage(jTextField1.getText());
            jTextField1.setText("");
            
          } // end of b1_ActionPerformed
          
          public void setOutMessage(String pOutMsg){
                 outMsg = pOutMsg;
          }
          
          public String getOutMessage(){
            return outMsg;  
          }

        
          



          // Ende Methoden
        } // end of class ClientGUI
        public class HandleClientGUI implements Runnable{
            ClientGUI cgui;
            
            public HandleClientGUI() {
                cgui = new ClientGUI();
            }
            
            public void run(){
                cgui = new ClientGUI();
            }
            public ClientGUI getCgui() {
                return cgui;
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.run();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. I suggest you narrow down your code and your question. Focus narrowly on one specific issue with a minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new, I suggest you stop using a swing and instead use Java FX If you use Java 8 as part of the JDK. In Java 11, JavaFX was removed from the SDK. It is now in its own separate module If you want to use it in your application, you will need to include it.
Here is a detailed explanation of how to get and include it.
https://blog.idrsolutions.com/using-javafx-with-java-11/

About your question: You cannot expect anybody to debug your code. I've checked your code unfortunately it is a mess and needs to be rewritten.
For example:
HandleClientGUI is not needed at all.
ClientGUI should not implement Runnable --> rename run() method to init() or something and invoke that method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I changed a few things and now it works perfectly:) Just one question, what do you mean with "stop using a swing"?
Thank you!

Comment: I mean there is a newer and more cleaner way to create java UI in JAAVA similar to Android. It basically saves all UI component metadata such as size location in an XML file. There is also utilities where you can drag and drop UI components. Search for tutorials online (Java FX.)